# Is there a change in V10 with Solve and exponents?

Tags: equation-solving

I've encountered a strange problem with V10. I can't quite nail it down, but the `Solve` seems to be unable to solve equations that it could in previous versions.   Here is one I'm almost positive I've done before.

```
Solve[q == l^a ((l w b)/(r a))^b, l]
```

For those who are wondering this is one of the steps in solving for a cost function using a Cobb–Douglas production function. It can obviously be solved, all *Mathematica* has to do is group the exponents.

Is there a change in the solve assumptions, options?  I've also tried being explicit about reals and allowing inverse functions.

Comment: For the example you give, V9 behaves exactly the same as V10.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
Solve[q == l^(a + b) ((w b)/(r a))^b // PowerExpand, l]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> ```
> {{l -> (a^b b^-b q r^b w^-b)^(1/(a + b))}}
> ```